# Проблема с подключением библиотеки

Tags: symfony, autoload

Предыстория такая: в приложении на symfony нужно отправлять уведомления на ios, android. Хочу использовать библиотеки GCMMessage и ApnsPHP. Composer без проблем cкачал их в  vendors.

Загвоздка в том, как использовать их в конкретном месте. С GCMMessage проблем нет - достаточно прописать use , а вот в ApnsPHP используется свой ApnsPHP_Autoload. Как его встроить в symfony?

Answer (score 1):

Нет необходимо отдельно что-то встраивать.

ApnsPHP так же доступен.

```
$push = new \ApnsPHP_Push(
    \ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX,
    'server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem'
);
```

autoload от ApnsPHP уже загружен через composer.